# asp .net mvc jqgrid returns error on post

Tags: asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller, jqgrid

My jqgrid is returning "The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request":

```
$('#list').jqGrid({
            url: "/DesktopModules/MVC/CW.GridTest/Item/getArtists2",
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "ModuleId": ModuleId,
                "TabId": TabId,
                "RequestVerificationToken": rvtoken
            },
            colNames: ['ArtistID', 'ArtistName', 'City'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'ArtistID', index: 'ArtistID', width: 80, align: 'left', editable: false },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'ArtistName', width: 120, align: 'left', editable: true },
                { name: 'Location', index: 'City',width: 60,align: 'left',editable: true,
                    edittype: "select",
                    editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx; IN:InTime; TN:TNT" }
                }
            ],
            height: '100%',  
            rowNum: 10,    
            emptyrecords: 'No records',  
            //sortname: 'ArtistName',
            //sortorder: 'desc',
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'jqGrid First Grid',
            width: 300,
            //gridview: true,
            jsonReader:  
            {  
                root: "rows",  
                page: "page",  
                total: "total",  
                records: "records",  
                repeatitems: false,  
                Id: "0"  
            },  
        });
```

While debugging, jqgrid never triggers my controller. I just get the error.

On the other hand, the exact same url works just fine in a standard ajax call:

```
function update() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        var rvtoken = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
        var ModuleId = @Dnn.ModuleContext.ModuleId;
        var TabId = @Dnn.ModuleContext.TabId;

        //$("#notice_div").html('Loading..');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/DesktopModules/MVC/CW.GridTest/Item/getArtists2",
            method: "Post",
            headers: {
                "ModuleId": ModuleId,
                "TabId": TabId,
                "RequestVerificationToken": rvtoken
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#dvBands").html(data + "<br/>" + new Date().toISOString());
                $("#notice_div").html('');
                window.setTimeout(update, 10000);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#notice_div").html('Timeout contacting server..');
                window.setTimeout(update, 60000);
            }

        });
```

The standard ajax works perfectly. I can see the entire Json string is formatted correctly.

How do I either correct the jqgrid to make its Ajax work, or correct my controller, or how do I set up jqgrid so that I can pass data to it from my working Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code don't work because you try to use `headers` option of `jQuery.ajax` method as the option of jqGrid. jqGrid don't have `headers` option, but you can use `loadBeforeSend` instead, where you call [jqXHR.setRequestHeader](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) method:

```
$('#list').jqGrid({
    url: "/DesktopModules/MVC/CW.GridTest/Item/getArtists2",
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "POST",
    loadBeforeSend: function (jqXhr) {
        var rvToken = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
        var moduleId = @Dnn.ModuleContext.ModuleId;
        var tabId = @Dnn.ModuleContext.TabId;

        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("ModuleId", moduleId);
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("TabId", tabId);
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken", rvToken);

        return true; // allow the Ajax request
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you.